# py2exe no module found

Tags: python, python-2.7, py2exe

I have python script main.py and two others scripts under.py and above.py which I imported to main.py, I also used additional modules and I want to make .exe file for Windows for distribution.
My setup.py looks like

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(console=['main.py'])
```

and when I run `python setup.py py2exe` I get dist folder with .dlls and main.exe file. When I start from command line main.exe I get error

```
No module urllib2 found
```

What can be a problem, urlib2 is used by some module which I use and I have installed via pip ( parse_rest module).
I looked in library.zip folder and there is urllib.pyc but nor urllib2.
When I from command line type python and in python 2.7 I can import module urllib2.

Comment: do you have different versions of python?

Comment: perhaps python 3 as well as python 2?

Comment: @dmg I am trying on same machine, same python and code works from PyCharm ide but when I pack and start from command line (sam python version 2.7 ) it doesn't work

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: @dmg I have installed 2.7 and 3.3 but in path in PyCharm is 2.7 and command line starts 2.7, I don't understand what do you suggest

Comment: In python 3, there is no urllib2. So, I suggest you make sure that all your paths point to python 2.